# Disabling supportsRtl in manifest does not stop lint warnings in the layouts

Tags: android, lint

I realised that disabling RTL language support in my manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

does not stop Lint from showing me his warnings/recommendations in the layouts about applying start/left instead of left/right.

Shouldn't Lint reading that value in the manifest and stop showing those warnings? Or is there another reason why it keeps showing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224949) in Oct 11 2016, but for now nothing as changed with AS 2.3 Beta 1

Comment: I thought it may be a reason for that, but i see it is just a known bug. Good to know! thanks bro!